# readline is reading more than one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

so the code is pretty simple, if the user doesn't enter a viable file then the program shuts down, however when I'm trying to move the opened files from the open_file() function to the main function, then use it in a read_file() function. However it's printing out more than just the first line when i go to print it to test it... im just trying to grab the 4th word separated by commas on the 2nd line.

```
#opens the file for data
def open_file():
    input_file = input("Enter a food crop file: ")
    try: 
        f1 = open(input_file,"r")
        next(f1)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found; terminating program.")
        return False,False
    input_file2 = input("Enter a non-food crop file: ")
    try:
        f2 = open(input_file2,"r")
        next(f2)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found; terminating program.")

        return False,False
    return f1,f2
def read_files(f1,f2):
    line1 = f1.readline()
    list_line1 = line1.replace(',','').split()
    product1 = list_line1[3]
    line2 = f2.readline()
    list_line2 = line2.replace(',','').split()
    product2 = list_line2[3]
    print(product1,product2)
    return product1,product2

#main fucntion, will call all other functions  
def main():
    f1,f2 = open_food_file()
    while f1 != False:


        product1,product2 = read_files(f1,f2)

#launches code
main()
```

It should look like this

```
Enter a food crop file: file_name.csv

Enter a non-food crop file: file_name.csv
product1 = 4th item in list for file1 here
product2 = 4th item in list for file2 here
```

it returns this, but then it errors out with

```
File "C:/COLLEGE/CSE/CSE 231/Code/redo.py", line 28, in read_files
    product1 = list_line1[3]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you provide example input and expected output?

Comment: @niemmi sure ill add it now

Comment: You are refering to the `read_files` function? ... that reads 2 lines? You say, _"when i go to print it to test it... "_ ... but you don't show us how you do that. Where do you print? Can you add a comment to code to show exactly where the print is?

Comment: @tdelaney its just there to make sure it's capturing the variables, I know it's doing that but I'm not sure why it's continuing to iterate lines and error out :/

Comment: `while f2 != False:` - since `f2` isn't False this is an infinite loop. Did you want `if` 's instead of `while` 's? But your actual error says that the line didn't split into at least 4 fields like you think it should. This could happen for instance, if you have an empty line after the two good data lines you expect. I don't know whether this happened on the first iteration of the infinite loop or later. If you want strict formatting of your file, you could catch the IndexError and terminate.

Comment: @tdelaney I opened both file's in the same function now and i have it return False,False if either are incorrect? It seems to be working well

Comment: Why are you calling `next()` on the file handles after opening them?

Comment: @tdelaney is there anyway I can get around the indexerror? i thought readline() only read one line, so why is it erroring out after that?

Comment: @tripleee there's unneeded information in the files on the first line for each

Comment: Your while loops cause `read_files` to be called many times. If you want to only call `read_files` once, then those whiles should be removed in favor of `if f1:` and `if f2:`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are reinventing CSV parsing?

Comment: @tdelaney if f1 = False then what? Having one while loop works for checking both, if either are found FIleNotFoundError then it exits and doesn't re-prompt

Comment: @tripleee I was taught that it was no different to read a CSV file than a TXT file so i treated it the same way

Comment: It's just a text file but parsing it by hand is brittle and unnecessary when there is a [`csv` module in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

Comment: I don't know what your new code looks like so I can't really say. And I don't know if you want to read the file more than once. But if you only want to read the file once, don't use a while.

Comment: @tdelaney sorry forgot to update it, I'm just not sure how to get around the IndexError so that I can continue using the files to pull more information from the next lines in a different function